# Unable to render data from my nodejs(after using select * query on mysql) to ejs page

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I fetched the results from mysql db and I am getting the data in my console but it wont render in my ejs page.
This is my .ejs page code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Date Formed</th>
  <th>Location</th>
</tr>

<%for(int i = 0;i < Allo.length; i++){%>
        <tr>
          <td><%=Allo.name%></td>
          <td><%=Allo.form_date%></td>
          <td><%=Allo.location%></td>
        </tr>
<%}%>

</table>
```

And this is my app.js:

```
    app.get("/Teams",function(req,res){
      db.query('SELECT * FROM team',function(err,result){
        console.log(result);
        res.render("Teams",{Foo:"",Allo:result});
    
      });
    
    });
```

The console.log(result) is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it guys. Using forEach solved the problem.

```
<% Allo.forEach(function(Allo){ %>
          <tr>
            <td><%=Allo.name%></td>
            <td><%=Allo.form_date%></td>
            <td><%=Allo.location%></td>
          </tr>
  <% })%>
```